# How to dump filesystem /dev/fuse in android?

Tags: android, filesystems

I want to dump /dev/fuse in my smartphone. I'm using Pantech Vega R3 which is Jellybean.

I'd try to the followings.

```
>adb shell
shell@android:/ $ dd if=/dev/fuse of=/storage/sdcard1 bs=2048
/dev/fuse: cannot open for read: Permission denied.
```

sdcard1 is external sd.

Do I have to root my phone? 
If I have to root , how can I root JellyBean?

I'm sorry that i'm not good at english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `ls -all /dev/fuse` in terminal reveals its permission `rw-------` and owner `root:root`. So, it cannot be read or `dd` without root access.